How to asses the memory requirement for x number of users browsing y number of pages
Here is the scenario. I need to get a rough idea of memory consumption of our corporate web site. We are running on Apache. The site is built using WordPress.
Is there a way to get the memory consumption of a single visitor who is connected to the web server?. so that I can get an estimate of an memory usage of x number of visitors. Assuming they are browsing an equal number of pages.
I have access to the web server via SSH only so any command line tool or command will do.
I have tried using php function memory_get_usage but this only returns an allocated amount not used amount.
I have also tried to get number of active http sessions using netstat | grep http | wc -l but don't have any idea on how to get the memory consumption of each session.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Static content (apache) is usually only loaded once in memory, it usually doesn't matter how many users view static content. Dynamic content on the other hand, like PHP, is addressed in another program, not apache, but php.

@paladin Thank you bro.

Enable mod_status in apache config and then visit https://your-website.com/server-status. You can then use Apache Benchmarking Tool to simulate load and get an idea of memory usage under concurrent users.
ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://your-website.com/

-n: Number of requests
-c: Number of concurrent requests


Thank you bro, I'll try that

Let me know if it works or if you need any more help.

bro is there anyway to get this command to show memory used for each requests?

Also Also mod_status already enabled but your-website.com/server-status returns 404, any thoughts?

There isn't a straightforward bult-in way to see memory usage per request directly, you can however enable extended status in mod_status in Apache config like so:
ExtendedStatus On
Restart Apache.
Now regarding the 404 error, ensure you properly configured mod_status in apache config.
